# PIE supported ssh server for android 5.1.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, ssh

I recently updated my moto E to  android 5.1.1.

When I executed dropbear binaries that used to work well on previous android versions, It showed this error :: `only position independent executables(PIE) are supported.`

I searched on net to fix this. Replaced linker file with patched one , but did not work. 
Searched for PIE supported dropbear binaries but could not find any.

Please give a link for PIE supported ssh server/dropbear or resolve this PIE issue ..

Comment: Servers Ultimate Pro appears to work in my device.

Comment: Any binary or app freely available on net ?

Comment: [Softwarerecs.se] would be a good place for recommendation. See [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060) or [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336)

Comment: if you build the dropbear with proper switches, it should work for you well.